# Php Smarty Variable with value if else

Tags: php, if-statement, smarty, whmcs

I'm sorry, I do not know how to ask the question because my knowledge is small.
I'll give an example of what I'm trying to do:

The message: `no records found` if you have no ticket in the department "7"

```
{if $ticket.did["7"] == ''} 
   No records found!
{/if}
```

My Whmcs tpl code:

```
{foreach from=$tickets item=ticket}
    {if $ticket.did == '7'}
    <tr>
        <td>#{$ticket.tid}</td> 
        <td>{$ticket.title}</td> 
        <td>{$ticket.status}</td>
        <td><a href="viewticket.php?tid={$ticket.tid}&c={$ticket.c}">View</a></td>
    </tr>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
    {if $ticket.did["7"] == ''} 
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="textcenter">{$LANG.norecordsfound}</td>
    </tr>
    {/if}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are the errors you are facing?

Comment: echo $ticket.did value after the for loop. see if you're getting the data.

Comment: @Vitor lima: The message and the list of tickets, the if else does not work.

Comment: @unixmiah: Yes. I getting the data from the last ticket sending.

Comment: use {if $ticket.dd eq 7}, don't use ticks around numbers

Comment: How to use the function if the department is "7" and it is "null"?

Comment: On use {if $ticket.did eq 7} I can only list the tickets to the corresponding department id '7'. I can not know whether or not tickets in the department '7'. Do you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize new variable and set it true when the condition in loop will be satisfied.

```
    {foreach from=$tickets item=ticket}
    {if $ticket.did == '7'}
    {assign var="ticketFound" value="true"}
    <tr>
        <td>#{$ticket.tid}</td> 
        <td>{$ticket.title}</td> 
        <td>{$ticket.status}</td>
        <td><a href="viewticket.php?tid={$ticket.tid}&c={$ticket.c}">View</a></td>
    </tr>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
    {if !$ticketFound} 
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="textcenter">{$LANG.norecordsfound}</td>
    </tr>
    {/if}
```